# My CNN predicts everything as zero

Tags: tensorflow, cnn

I have ~4000 3D images with 0,1,2 labels. 70% of the labels are zeros.
The dimension of each image is [40, 30, 30]
The values usually range between -50 to 50 and about 10% of each image has non-zero values(bigger than 10^-4).

The below is my 3D CNN model with 3 pooling layers and 3 fully connected layers.

```
self.conv1 = conv3d(self.X, 10, 1, 32, name='conv1')
self.norm1 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(self.conv1, center=True, scale=True, scope='bn1')
self.pool1 = max_pool(self.norm1, 3, 2, name='pool1')
self.conv2 = conv3d(self.pool1,8,1,64, name='conv2')
self.norm2 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(self.conv2, center=True, scale=True, scope='bn2')
self.pool2 = max_pool(self.norm2, 3, 2, name='pool2') 
self.conv3 = conv3d(self.pool2,8,1,64, name='conv3')
self.pool3 = max_pool(self.conv3, 3, 2, name='pool3') 
proddim = np.prod(self.pool3.get_shape()[1:], dtype=np.uint)

self.flat = tf.reshape(self.pool3, [-1,proddim ])

self.fc4 = fc(self.flat, num_output=1024, name='fc4')
self.dropout4 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=self.fc4, rate=0.2, training=self.dropout_train, name='dropout4')
self.fc5 = fc(self.dropout4, num_output=384, name='fc5')
self.dropout5 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=self.fc5, rate=0.2, training=self.dropout_train, name='dropout5')  
self.fc6 = fc(self.dropout5, num_output=3, name='fc6')
```

I double, triple checked that the inputs are correct but my model always predict everything as zero.

Is it because my tensor or labels mostly have zero values? Or do I have too little data?

Comment: what is self? why aren't you making tensors separately?

Comment: @Media `self` is just Python OO, huddy is storing the TF tensors and operations against an object as opposed to as contents of a `dict`, but otherwise it is the same idea.

Comment: Are you importing `conv3d` from `tf.nn` or `tf.layers`, or from somewhere else? There is a difference, but some may look the same in your code.

Comment: @NeilSlater nice idea I guess, haven't seen such coding, thanks :)

Comment: @NeilSlater  my 'conv3d' uses tf.nn.conv3d  and 'max_pool' uses tf.nn.max_pool3d.   You mean  I should stick to either tf.layers or tf.nn?  I am using tf.contrib.layers for batch normalization